# Include logo of cooperating company on thesis cover

Tags: thesis, acknowledgement, formatting

I've just finished writing my master's thesis, which heavily relied on data that I received from a municipality. The data was collected within a project that was mainly conducted by colleagues of mine in behalf of the municipality (I'm working half-time).

I obviously mention the municipality and my main contact there as well as the company I work for and 2 of my colleagues in my acknowledgements.

Would you include the logo of either the municipality and/or the company on the cover? 
What other options do I have? 
(engineering science in Germany, if that matters)

Comment: What do the municipality, the company, and the university say about this? Are you allowed to modify the thesis cover at all?

Comment: This question should have been put in a five-line email, not on the internet.

Comment: Have you considered adding the logo on a different page than the cover (a benefactor page perhaps)?

Comment: I have written my thesis in cooperation with a very well known research institute and included their logo opposite of my universities' logo on the title page. But smallish, on the bottom. Graduated in CS also in Germany.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The thesis is a scientific work, and it is the university that is responsible for it. The fact that you got someone funding you or that you performed the science somewhere else doesn't change this fact. I would keep the cover as simple as possible, and include only the university logo, and maybe even not that one.

Note that inclusion of logos of institutions that fund you seems to be a thing now. Sometimes rules are set up that the logo has to be on every slide of every talk that the people perform. This means that for some people, the slides are unusable, because they contain 5 or 6 logos. Some authors try to get their logo in an article they publish in the journal I typeset/copy edit; we have hard times explaining them that this is not acceptable in the journal and that only text acknowledgements are possible. Journals are quite strict on this, conferences commence to limit this as well.

Please, do not support this logo frenzy. If you really really want to include the logos, present them nicely in the acknowledgements section.

Comment: That last line is golden

Comment: In contrast, there are also some conferences that mandate logos on only one slide.

Comment: @Fomite Yes I know, forgot to mention it.